# Getting polar and cartesian forms of an expression MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following expression:
z = 4e−2j(2−3j)/(√3e2j)

I have to get the polar and cartesian forms of this expression in MATLAB. I have already did some research but I can't find a way to do it..

Can someone explain me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define

```
 z = 4*exp(2*j) * (2-3*j) / sqrt(3*exp(2*j));
```

and then compute

```
abs(z) % modulus (magnitude)
angle(z) % argument (phase) in radians
real(z) % real part
imag(z) % imaginary part
```

Is that what you want?